# codeigniter join table by number and not a nother table

Tags: codeigniter, join

When i try to make a this join in codeigniter

```
$this->db->join('ticketsale','ticketsale.id = 1');
```

i get this error: Unknown column '1' in 'on clause'

```
"SELECT * FROM (`users`) JOIN `ticketsale ` ON `ticketsale `.`id` = `1` JOIN `ticketsale_.."
```

how do I get codeigniter to not putting `` around 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in join statement, You must use column name for match them and joining other query.If you want to do that, you should add Where statement.
For example:

```
"SELECT * FROM (`users`) JOIN `ticketsale ` ON `ticketsale `.`id` = `hereyourtable`.`hereis the column` JOIN `ticketsale_..  WHERE `ticketsale `.`id`=1"
```

**UPDATED:**
Also, In active records;

```
 $this->db->join("ticketsale","ticketsale.id=users.column")->where("ticketsale.id"=>"1");
this query will return same as native sql query
```